# Show blinking control on top of uinavigationbar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I want to achieve same functionality in my app that iOS provider while call is going on in background.

i.e. On some condition i want to show a blinking button on top of screen (On statusbar and navigationbar)withing the application and when user taps on that button i want to push a particular view controller on the same.

Refer the screenshot 
[image]

What would be the bet solution to achieve this ?

I have tried this

```
 UIButton *hideBtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)]; 
[hideBtn addTarget:delegate.familyJobMonitorViewController action:@selector(hideAndShowView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [delegate.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:hideBtn];
```

It's working fine but i have to manage many things manually in this case. Is there anything better available

direct API or something inbuilt in cocoa for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CoreAnimation` to cycle an animation, in this case toggling the opacity of the layer.  By setting `autoreverses = true` the animation will cycle between `fromValue` and `toValue`  By setting `repeatCount = MAXFLOAT` the animation will run until stopped.

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    BOOL        _blinking;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button setTitle:@"Tap to Resume" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onResume:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = button;
}

-(IBAction)onResume:(id)sender
{
    [self toggleBlinking];
}

-(void)toggleBlinking
{
    CALayer*    layer = self.navigationItem.titleView.layer;

    _blinking = !_blinking;

    if(!_blinking)
    {
        [layer removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity"];
    }
    else
    {
        CABasicAnimation*    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.fromValue = @(1.0);
        animation.toValue = @(0.0);
        animation.duration = 1.0;
        animation.autoreverses = true;
        animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;

        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I want to add This on top of my navigation bar which already have another title. So setting title view won't work. but i can use this animation code. Thanks